# How should I create this relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

In my previous question, I've mentioned that I'm developing a Point of Sale application. The platforms I use are WPF, MVVM and Entity Framework (code-first). Since Entity Framework code-first has its own logic to map entities and relations, I'm confused about a case.

I have an `EntityBase` class:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Since `User` class has `EntityBase` class members, will it arise problems at database side?

Or should I keep the data like this:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your models in this way:

```
public class EntityBase
    {
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int CreatedById { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public int UpdatedById { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UpdatedById")]
        public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```